# Redux-form Fields by default Initial values disappear when Text box changes to empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form, saga

I am using Redux-Form version 8.2.4.

I have declared some Objects by default to be null :

```
import { FieldArray } from 'redux-form';

 this.props.addValues({ value 1: null, value 2: null })

 <FieldArray name="TestData" component={this.getData}/>
```

When i am using onChange function in Textbox, the values assigned in the field is pushing into the array. But when the textbox is empty the field values removed from the array itself.

I want to keep by default value in the state is null instead of removing from the array.

I have used:

```
onChildParamInit={this.onChildParamInit.bind(this)}

onChildParamInit = () => {
this.props.change('value1' , null);
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Please share some more code or even better create a code sandbox to reproduce the issue